# Why need extra step by using http.proxyHost for apache camel http component

Tags: http, apache-camel, system-properties

By using http.proxyHost for apache camel http component .
It need two steps below, otherwise http.proxy will not work for camel http component.

1. put -Dhttp.proxyHost  at java command line
2. at camel http query paramter, setting useSystemProperties to true

but for javax.net.ssl.trustStore , step 2 is not need.

Since  both of them(trustStore or httpProxy) are system properties could be used via java command line.
Why http.proxyHost need step2, but javax.net.ssl.trustStore  does not ?
Could anyone have some idea?

Thanks in advancace!

Answer (score 0):

*Apache Camel HTTP* component provide a per URI / Endpoint way of configuring an HTTP proxy:

```java
from("direct:start")
    .to("http://somehost?proxyAuthHost=www.someproxy.com&proxyAuthPort=80");
```

Adds to that a way to override proxy configuration using a context global options:

```java
context.getGlobalOptions().put("http.proxyHost", "someproxy");
context.getGlobalOptions().put("http.proxyPort", "someport");
```

This allows the `org.apache.http.client.HttpClient` to be consider configuration precedence when resolving and creating the HTTP proxy:

- If the system properties (for the HTTP proxy) are there those will be resolved and loaded
- If the HTTP proxy global options are there, those will be resolved and used instead of system properties
- If an endpoint HTTP proxy configuration has been set then this configuration will be resolved and used

All of the configuration resolution steps can be skipped altogether to **fallback** on using all HTTP(S) related properties (within the underlying `org.apache.http.client.HttpClient`) **from the system properties** if the user wishes so by setting the `useSystemProperties` component option.

As a summary, you can think of the HTTP related properties resolution process as providing a set of **flexible** configuration options to the user to fit in all use cases.